# MonoTouch.Dialog Elements can be null when search bar used too quick

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have a `DialogViewController` with many elements and a search bar. When a user taps between the search bar and the cancel button fast, the `Elements` node of the `Section` in the following `MonoTouch.Dialog.Elements.cs` code is sometimes null so it throws an error and the app is torn down by the OS. Is there a work around?

From `Elements.cs`, latest Git version. Only happens on a real device.

[image]

Comment: I found this 'bug' too - I am just catching the NullReferenceException and ignoring it as there is always another search.

Comment: https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/issues/94 bug reported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To turn this into an answer - I think this is a bug.

I have filed it at:

- https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/issues/94

And produced a sample which reproduces the bug at:

- https://github.com/Macropus/Bug-Reports/blob/master/BugReport94/BugReport94/AppDelegate.cs

I think it may be a threading synchronisation issue where the thread is trying to access the Root.Elements but they have been removed by the Cancel button.